# Parsing URL string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, url, uri, tokenize

I have a pretty simple string I want to parse in ruby and trying to find the most elegant solution.  The string is of format
/xyz/mov/exdaf/daeed.mov?arg1=blabla&arg2=3bla3bla

What I would like to have is :
string1: /xyz/mov/exdaf/daeed.mov
string2: arg1=blabla&arg2=3bla3bla

so basically tokenise on ?

but can't find a good example. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I think the best solution would be to use the `URI` module.  (You can do things like `URI.parse('your_uri_string').query` to get the part to the right of the `?`.)  See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/

Example:

```
002:0> require 'uri' # or even 'net/http'
true
003:0> URI
URI
004:0> URI.parse('/xyz/mov/exdaf/daeed.mov?arg1=bla&arg2=asdf')
#<URI::Generic:0xb7c0a190 URL:/xyz/mov/exdaf/daeed.mov?arg1=bla&arg2=asdf>
005:0> URI.parse('/xyz/mov/exdaf/daeed.mov?arg1=bla&arg2=asdf').query
"arg1=bla&arg2=asdf"
006:0> URI.parse('/xyz/mov/exdaf/daeed.mov?arg1=bla&arg2=asdf').path
"/xyz/mov/exdaf/daeed.mov"
```

Otherwise, you can capture on a regex: `/^(.*?)\?(.*?)$/`.  Then `$1` and `$2` are what you want.  (`URI` makes more sense in this case though.)

Comment: You could just require 'uri' instead of 'net/http'

Comment: Good point; I always forget about that because I usually download something right after I parse a URI.

Answer (score 10):

Split the initial string on question marks.

```
str.split("?")
=> ["/xyz/mov/exdaf/daeed.mov", "arg1=blabla&arg2=3bla3bla"]
```

Comment: There's already a URL parsing library that would probably be a better choice if the input is always a URL.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be what youre looking for, strings built-in split function:

```
"abc?def".split("?") => ["abc", "def"]
```

**Edit**: Bah, to slow ;)