# Get id from string with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have strings like this:

- "/detail/205193-foo-var-bar-foo.html"
- "/detail/183863-parse-foo.html"
- "/detail/1003-bar-foo-bar.html"

How to get ids (205193, 183863, 1003) from it with **Ruby**?

Comment: possible dups: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899953/whats-the-ruby-way-to-parse-a-string-for-a-single-key-value 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208137/parsing-string-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could also do something like this

```
"/detail/205193-foo-var-bar-foo.html".gsub(/\/detail\//,'').to_i
 => 205193
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Just say `s[/\d+/]`

---

```
[
 "/detail/205193-foo-var-bar-foo.html",
 "/detail/183863-parse-foo.html",
 "/detail/1003-bar-foo-bar.html"
].each { |s| puts s[/\d+/] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = /\/detail\/(\d+)-/
s = "/detail/205193-foo-var-bar-foo.html"
id = regex.match s  # => <MatchData "/detail/205193-" 1:"205193">
id[1]               # => "205193"
$1                  # => "205193"
```

The `MatchData` object will store the entire matched portion of the string in the first element, and any matched subgroups starting from the second element (depending on how many matched subgroups there are)

Also, Ruby provides a shortcut to the most recent matched subgroup with `$1` .

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do it would be to strip out the `/detail/` part of your string, and then just call `to_i` on what's left over:

`"/detail/1003-bar-foo-bar.html".gsub('/detail/','').to_i # => 1003`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "/detail/205193-foo-var-bar-foo.html"
num = (s =~ /detail\/(\d+)-/) ? Integer($1) : nil
```

Comment: -:2: invalid regular expression; there's no previous pattern, to which '+' would define cardinality at 10: /detail\/(+d)-/